# Suggested Web Application Framework and Database for Enterprise, “Big-Data” App?

Tags: database, web-applications, web-framework, big-data

I have a web application that I have been developing for a small group within my company over the past few years, using Pipeline Pilot (plus jQuery and Python scripting) for web development and back-end computation, and Oracle 10g for my RDBMS. Users upload experimental genomic data, which is parsed into a database, and made available for querying, transformation, and reporting.

Experimental data sets are large and have many layers of metadata.  A given experimental data record might have a foreign key relationship with a table that describes this data point's assay. Assays can cover multiple genes, which can have multiple transcript, which can have multiple mutations, which can affect multiple signaling pathways, etc.  Users need to approach this data from any point in those layers in the metadata. Since all data sets for a given data type can run over a billion rows, this results in some large, dynamic queries that are hard to predict.

New data sets are added on a weekly basis (~1GB per set).  Experimental data is never updated, but the associated metadata can be updated weekly for a few records and yearly for most others.  For every data set insert the system sees, there will be between 10 and 100 selects run against it and associated data.  It is okay for updates and inserts to run slow, so long as queries run quick and are as up-to-date as possible.

The application continues to grow in size and scope and is already starting to run slower than I like.  I am worried that we have about outgrown Pipeline Pilot, and perhaps Oracle (as the sole database). Would a NoSQL database or an OLAP system be appropriate here? What web application frameworks work well with systems like this? I'd like the solution to be something scalable, portable and supportable X-years down the road.

Here is the current state of the application:

- Web Server/Data Processing: Pipeline Pilot on Windows Server + IIS
- Database: Oracle 10g, ~1TB of data, ~180 tables with several billion-plus row tables
- Network Storage: Isilon, ~50TB of low-priority raw data

Comment: I'd love to be able to pick a best answer at this point, because people have given some great advice, but management has kicked the can down the road for this project and I will not have a resolution any time soon.  We are currently exploring a few options, such as Hadoop and Oracle OLAP.  The web application will probably be moved off Pipeline Pilot and on to Java Spring Framework.

Answer (score 2):

Since the data is mostly immutable, have you looked into possible denormalizations? The goal would be to find values that could be essentially duplicated but reduce query complexity.

If queries regulary chain joins to connect to pieces of data, you can create a duplicate foreign key relationship directly between the two tables.

If there is a calculation performed by several queries, perform it once and save the result in the appropriate table. For example, some property of the assays that is calculated when needed can be calculated when inserted and added the the assay table.

This is ultimately what a Data Warehouse type solution does, but on a much smaller scale.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you finalized on a solution, but my two cents for those who stumble on this question:
There are two parts (1) Database (2) Web App framework.

On Database, Did you explore Hadoop? Following specs of your environment makes Hadoop an attractive platform for data processing.

1. ~1TB of data,  ~50TB of low-priority raw data
2. several billion-plus row tables
3. New data sets are added on a weekly basis (~1GB per set)
4. Experimental data is never updated, but the associated metadata can be updated weekly/yearly
5. Insert to Select ratio is 10 to 100 times
6. all data sets for a given data type can run over a billion rows

Following specs are of concern though:

1. large, dynamic queries that are hard to predict.
2. (okay for updates and inserts to run slow,) so long as queries run quick

Hadoop is insanely scalable, but Hadoop performs the best with batch processing. For online queries YMMV. Unless you try out it will be hard to predict if you will be better of or worse. You have to experiment with Hive, Cloudera Impala etc. This [Article](http://www.informationweek.com/software/information-management/cloudera-impala-brings-sql-querying-to-h/240153861) has some introductory overview on Impala. It also mentions some other options.

If Hive/Impala are not giving you right performance, there are variations you can explore based on your environment

1. Since Disk space is comparably cheap, generate a lot more "summarized intermediate" tables, that could speed up queries.
2. Pre join meta data, if that can reduce number of joins in the queries
3. Use some hybrid approach of Oracle + Hadoop (but with increased overall complexity).

Answer (score 0):

You probably would not have to concern yourself with a particular web framework. Just ensure that your apps are readily disributable/clusterable (avoid specific file system dependencies, ensure it can run on any system with a single build, ...) and that your systems are set up to handle multiple nodes.

As far as the backend it really depends on your functionality; you want to choose a datastore(s) that makes sense for your app. You would want to look at the various categories of "NoSQL" type data stores (document, graph, key-value, ...) to see if one or many can be appropriate for your needs. You will also want to ensure that Oracle or another RDBMS actually has limitations your business cannot live with (ex/ have you looked at RAC?).

**In short, there is no good answer to this question. Understand your needs, isolate your bottlenecks, know your options, and don't be afraid to mix solutions where appropriate.**

Comment: I am not looking for THE answer, just suggestions of what may be worthwhile avenues to pursue.  There are a lot of options out there.  Everything you suggest in your first paragraph, the current application is NOT.

Comment: @willOEM if you are not looking for *the* answer, the Q&A format may be a bad fit for this question.  You might want to consider asking it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard).

Comment: I am certainly open for suggestions for other places to ask this question.  I know this is a little open-ended, but I don't think asking what technologies other people use for similar applications is outside of the Q&A scope.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to scale - up (bigger/better/faster boxes) and out (more boxes).  Up is good to a point, but no one is making off the shelf petaflop boxes yet.  Out takes more work, but if you have removed the bottlenecks there's no significant limit on how many boxes can be run in parallel.

Based on your comments it sounds like you have some bottlenecks to remove so you're clusterable etc.

As for whether or not you've outgrown Pipeline Pilot, that's a question that the vendor can best answer.

Comment: Also, make sure you're doing the obvious things like indexing your tables and not doing anything too naive with your queries.  I just spent a week here refactoring some old code where someone had written lots of simple database queries, in loops, nested 4 levels deep, and then filtered the data *in code*, rather than using "WHERE" clauses in the queries.

Comment: Database tables are indexed and partitioned where appropriate.  I have spent a lot of time optimizing SQL to squeeze the best performance out of my queries.  It is problematic where use-cases dictate that many large tables be joined together for desired results.  Figuring out how to best handle these situations has led me to look someplace other than the current setup.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement of searching for arbitrary data and dynamic queries is a good use case for an in memory database.

Disclaimer for the rest of the answer: I work for SAP, so I am most familiar with SAP's products.

SAP already solved a similar use case (genome analysis) already with it's in memory database HANA, so it works. Read more about it here:
http://www.saphana.com/docs/DOC-1799

Programming in HANA is mostly done using stored procedures. HANA has a build in Javascript runtime to implement the application layer. Or you can expose the stored procedures as services and use any other app server on top (e.g. Java).

You can find tutorials and trial development environments here:
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/cross-technology
More information:
http://scn.sap.com/community/hana-in-memory